# Saving an Object containing Bitmap

Tags: android, serialization, bitmap, gson

I'm working on an android application (first application-beginner) and I'm trying to save data when the app closes to load again.

The data I want to store is a list of books, and each book contains info (author, date, etc) and a bitmap containing the book's picture. I tried using GSON to convert the list to JSON and store in SharedPreferences but that caused problems because of the bitmap.

How should I save the file and retrieve it again when the app launches ?

This is a brief version of the code

**Library Class**

```
public class Library {

        private ArrayList<Entry> library ;

        public Library () {
            library = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        }

        public void addEntry( Entry entry ) {
            library.add(entry);
        }

        public void removeEntry ( Entry entry ) {
            if (library.contains(entry))
                library.remove(entry);
            else Log.d ( "Library" , "Entry Not Found");
        }

        public ArrayList<Entry> getLibrary() {
            return library;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Library{" +
                    "library=" + library +
                    '}';
        }
}
```

**Entry Class**

```
public class Entry {
    Book book ;
    final LocalDate borrowDate; 
    LocalDate dueDate;

    //some methods for application
}
```

**Book Class**

```
public class Book implements Parcelable {

private String title;
private String author;
private String isbn ;
private double rating;
private int ratingCount;
private int pageCount;
private transient Bitmap image;
private String overview;
//some methods 
}
```

Comment: Note that I have used Parcelable to transfer book objects between activities, that is why I implemented Parcelable in Book Class

Comment: so how you are generating bitmaps? is that from a link?

Comment: Yes, the bitmap and other book info are all extracted from a link

Comment: u can directly load the image url using http://square.github.io/picasso/ LIBRARY  in that case save the url as string and use to load image when ever required

Comment: Hmmm, this seems like a viable solution, but what if I want to store the information so I can open the app and check offline without having a connection  ?

Comment: that library will cache the image so no need to worry on that it will be loaded without internet also after the first time load

Comment: Using the Glide also can provide the better cache and optimized bimaps.

Comment: What do you mean by Glide ?

Comment: You should save the link of the image not the bitmap. This will consume more space and processing resources, Large Bitmap can cause OOM.

Comment: yea u can use any image caching libraries like universal image loader ,glide or Square Picasso . Saving bitmap >> encode and decode is bad approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the bitmap in sharedpreferences. Save it in file.

If you need to persist the bitmap, you can assign it to a static field.

You can also convert it to a 64 bit String.. but that is bad design (and I think it is a very slow and expensive operation!):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

^ Save that to SharedPreferece. Now to decode:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(encoded.getBytes());
ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```

Comment: So in the book class I should remove the Bitmap altogether and instead, after downloading the bitmap compress it and store it as a string in the class ? and then whenever I have to use it in an image view I would do the decode operation first?

Comment: That is the very expensive way of doing it. Faster would be to save the thing. SharedPreferences... isn't really designed to do this

Comment: How do I save it then ? that was my original problem. And how expensive/slow is it ?

Comment: Also what do you think of Sishin's solution in the comments? would it be better and inexpensive to do it that way ?

Comment: His solution works if you're loading your images from a url. If from another source (file, etc) it may be different. But yes, it is another solution and will be faster code as Picasso is a library optimized for loading images from the web, designed to reduce problems like the one you have (assuming you're loading an image from the web)

Comment: @lawonga glide or Square Picasso will work well with URL,File URI, or File

Answer (score 2):

Use Picasso and load the urls directly instead of downloading and saving as bitmap

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load("imageURL here")
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_pic)
                        .error(R.drawable.error_pic)

                        .resizeDimen(100, 100)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(holderOrderHistory.mIcon);
```